# Offset mirrored geometry

Tags: modifiers, mirror, geometry

I'm trying to offset the mirrored geometry procedurally.

For example, here I have some beams with two simple deforms and a mirror modifier:

[image: With modifiers]

But I wish to have the beams interlace and look like this:

[image: Manual result example]

Which I got by applying all the modifiers and manually moving one side along the x axis a bit.

I want to find a solution that doesn't involve having to apply all the modifiers, for example being able to offset the mirrored side of the geometry, is this possible?

Blend file for anyone interested:
[image]

Comment: you can choose the mirroring point: add an empty and mirror by that empty. is it what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually a linked duplication of your object would be simpler than any solution: Duplicate your object with <kbd>Atl</kbd><kbd>D</kbd>, flip it on the Y axis with <kbd>S</kbd><kbd>Y</kbd><kbd>-1</kbd> and move it so that the 2 objects cross each others.

But other than that I was able to do it with the *Array* modifier. It looks like you can't shift the object with the *Mirror* modifier(?).

- Create an empty close to your object.

[image]

- Give your object an *Array* modifier, disable *Relative Offset*, enable *Object Offset* with the empty as *Object*.

[image]

- Select your empty, flip it on the Y axis with <kbd>S</kbd><kbd>Y</kbd><kbd>-1</kbd>. The object is mirrored on the Y axis.

[image]

- Move the empty so that the objects cross the way you want.

[image]